# Removing "- Any -" option from Drupal view drop down filer

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a drop down search and for some reason I cannot get rid of the "- Any -" option which looks like this:

[image]

These were the options that I selected for my content filter:

[image]

Would anyone have any suggestions about what to do for this? I have looked into using different modules but still cant figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://bit.ly/1c1TkHr or http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83678/drupal-7-views-exposed-filter-removing-any-and-sorting-items

Comment: @chrisjlee - Yeah... I have tried to google the issue and that still does not really solve my question. Where am i supposed to put that code? I guess I should have also put in my question, is there a way to do this in the drupal UI? Trust me, i know how to google and select the first link that pops up too... I was looking for a little more depth to the answer seeing it is how i am a new drupal user. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where it says "Optional" in your screenshot, "This exposed filter is optional and will have added options to allow it not to be set".

Uncheck that.